# How can I ensure detected bounding boxes are of the same size in YOLOv5

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, bounding-box, yolov5

I'm working with YOLOv5 for object detection and I'm encountering an issue where the bounding boxes for detected objects have varying sizes. I want to standardize the bounding box sizes to be the same for all detected objects. How can I achieve this in YOLOv5? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated!